# return function values as pointer

Tags: c++, function, pointers, return

Question:

> Make function which will sum two integer variables (a,b) and then return result in variable ***rez*** , using pointer. Also, in the same function,  return sum **a+b+10** in another variable **rez_a** using pointer.

Well, here is the code. It returns only the first value (*p1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 
int vrati(int a, int b) {
    int rez = a + b;
    int rez_a = a + b + 10;
    int* p1 = &rez;
    int* p2 = &rez_a;
    return *p1,*p2;
}

int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 6;
    cout << vrati(a, b);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is explained in any beginner level [C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). In particular, no C++ book will teach you to write: `return *p1,*p2;`.

Comment: Actually, it returns only the second value. That's what comma operator does in C++.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are taking `return` too literally. I expect the function you are meant to write is this

```
void vrati(int a, int b, int *rez, int* rez_a) {
    *rez = a + b;
    *rez_a = a + b + 10;
}

int main() {
    int a = 4;
    int b = 6;
    int rez, rez_a;
    vrati(a, b, &rez, &rez_a);
    cout << rez << ' ' << rez_a;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This function returns values, but it doesn't use `return`. I can understand why you were confused.